# Launching a floating window/ iframe without an AJAX framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, yui

As such I need to be able to open an iframe as a layer on the page but can't load up a framework given the weight and potential for conflicts as this is an addon to other sites.

The goal here is to be as light as possible while also avoiding crossover since sites using it may have jquery / yui or other scripting frameworks involved. The page is multi-part so a simple layer won't do, it has to be a full fledged iFrame with the ability to fade the underlying window and close it down while also floating over page elements, drop downs, even flash.

Colorbox-min would be an ideal solution but the dependancy kills it.

I do pretty well with frameworks but on my own am a JS novice. In a world full of ready made scripts, Google isn't being much help... Any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: may be you can clarify exactly what you're trying to do, from the description it seems you're trying to do a dialog plugin? what do you mean by a multi-part page or "simple layer"?

Comment: Sure thing! I am looking to open an iFrame ontop of the existing window to load external documents into. These windows appear to be part of the same page and close down if the page is closed.This is commonly done with a plugin like Colorbox but these require frameworks like jquery or yui which, beyond being fairly large in size, also have the potential to clash with other scripts also using the framework so I am looking for guidance to open the window directly, no major system behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create an iframe and insert it to your page without using any framework, so here it is:

```
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.src= "http://www.google.com";
frame.width = "200";
frame.height = "200";
frame.style.position = "absolute";
frame.style.top = "30px";
frame.style.left = "30px";
frame.style.border = "solid 1px red";
document.getElementById("IdOfContainer").appendChild(frame);
```

Now, just for the sake of discussion, using jquery or yui or some other good quality library normally does not have any problems with clashes with other scripts, they take great care in protecting themselves from other scripts and not polluting other scripts namespaces.

[Here's a working sample of plain javascript and other using jquery](http://jsbin.com/ituma6/3/edit)

Comment: This worked for me, except (1) Since the position of the frame is absolute, you can attach it to any element, so I just chose the button instead of "IdOfContainer". (2) I can see through the floating iframe, which I got rid of with, $(frame).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');.  (Don't forget, it's 200x200 pixels, so it won't show anything in google.com until you scroll down!)